# ¿Como se en cual indice esta el for al recorrer un Json array?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, jsonarray

estoy empezando en javascript y estoy aprendiendo acerca de recorrer y mostrar un json Array, lo que ocurre es que quiero conocer la posicion en la que se encuentra el for en ese momento, para asi asignar el id a cada componente.

En este caso tengo 5 elementos asi que utilizo un for para recorrerlos

```
for(let arr of request){
  //Aqui quiero saber si es es el primero, segundo, tercero... etc.
}
```

No se como puedo hacer esto, lo que se me ocurrio fue crear una variable afuera del for que tenga `request.lenght` y luego dentro del for ir sumandolo. Pero depronto hay una mejor forma de hacerlo.

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es utilizar el `for of` puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
var Array = ["Prueba","Test"]

for (let [indice, valor] of Array.entries()) {
    console.log('%d: %s', indice, valor);
}
```

Te dejo la documentación de la función `entries()` por si la necesitas: [Array​.prototype​.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/entries)

Espero sea de tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Definitivamente me funcionó, gracias :D, eso era lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

supongamos que tienes este array:

```
var frutas = ['Manzana', 'Banana'];
```

puedes recorrerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
frutas.forEach(function (elemento, indice, array) {
    console.log(elemento, indice); //reemplaza aquí por lo que necesites
});
```

El código anterior recorre el array y hace una función, que hace el console.log, imprimiendo el elemento actual y el índice. Donde `elemento` vendría siento el valor en el array, `indice` es el número que buscas, y `array` es el array que recorres. Para confirmarlo se ve el console.log.

Para más información acerca de arrays, puedes checar la [documentación de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)